# Create kubernetes yml file from docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this docker-compose.yml file which I am using to run up three microservices and one api gateway

```
version: '3'
services: 
    serviceone:
        container_name: serviceone
        restart: always
        build: serviceone/
        ports: 
            - '3000:3000'
    servicetwo:
        container_name: servicetwo
        restart: always
        build: servicetwo/
        ports: 
            - '3001:3001'   
    servicethree:
        container_name: servicethree
        restart: always
        build: servicethree/
        ports: 
             - '3002:3003'    
    apigateway:
        container_name: timezoneapigateway
        restart: always
        build: timezone/
        ports: 
            - '8080:8080'
        links: 
            - serviceone
            - servicetwo
            - servicethree
```

Now I want to deploy these dockerimages in one pod in kubernetes so that the api gateway can connect with all the three microservices ,current version of api gateway is working but I am really not getting even a slightest hint of doing this in kubernetes. I am really new to kubernetes can anyone tell me how to design a kubernetes yml file to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run all your service in the same pod. The standard in Kubernetes is to have separate deployments and services for all apps. Here is a deployment manifest for *serviceone* but you can easily modify it for *servicetwo*, *servicethree* and *apigateway*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceone
  labels:
    app: serviceone
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serviceone
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serviceone
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: serviceone
        image: serviceone:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
```

And the same goes for the service manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serviceone
spec:
  selector:
    app: serviceone
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
```

Your services will be accessible within the cluster like this:

```
serviceone:3001
servicetwo:3002
servicethree:3003
timezoneapigateway:8080
```

Comment: So how I will be able to connect serviceone with apigateway?

Comment: All services will be accessible with name and port from the service manifest

Comment: I have tried every possible combination but its not working

Comment: Can you give me some more details? Were is your cluster running, cloud provider, bare metal, or minikube? What is not working, connecting the services, accessing the gateway, or deploying the apps?

Comment: its running on minikube @jokarls